# Starting KSQL on a SASL secured Confluent server, gives error "Value not specified for key 'â' in JAAS config"

Tags: apache-kafka, jaas, confluent-platform, ksqldb

When starting KSQL using the ksql-server.properties file with:

```
sasl.jaas.config=org.apache.kafka.common.security.scram.ScramLoginModule required \
        username="<username>" \
        password="<password with @ and special chars>";
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
sasl.mechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256
```

I get an error:

```
ERROR Failed to start KSQL (io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain:48)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed create new KafkaAdminClient
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:370)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.AdminClient.create(AdminClient.java:62)
    at io.confluent.ksql.util.KafkaTopicClientImpl.<init>(KafkaTopicClientImpl.java:66)
    at io.confluent.ksql.KsqlEngine.<init>(KsqlEngine.java:120)
    at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlRestApplication.buildApplication(KsqlRestApplication.java:252)
    at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.createExecutable(KsqlServerMain.java:83)
    at io.confluent.ksql.rest.server.KsqlServerMain.main(KsqlServerMain.java:45)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Value not specified for key 'â' in JAAS config
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasConfig.parseAppConfigurationEntry(JaasConfig.java:116)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasConfig.<init>(JaasConfig.java:63)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.load(JaasContext.java:90)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.security.JaasContext.loadClientContext(JaasContext.java:84)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.create(ChannelBuilders.java:119)
    at org.apache.kafka.common.network.ChannelBuilders.clientChannelBuilder(ChannelBuilders.java:65)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils.createChannelBuilder(ClientUtils.java:88)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.KafkaAdminClient.createInternal(KafkaAdminClient.java:346)
```

specifically, the error:

```
Value not specified for key 'â' in JAAS config
```

is throwing me off - the keys in JAAS config should be only username and password - right?

created a client.properties file in my confluent server with the exact same username password and SASL_Plaintext.

Comment: I think passwords can only be utf8 strings, and not have characters like â

Comment: I have an ampersand character in the password - dont have the â character anywhere in my ksql-server.propetries document. any idea where that could be coming from?

Comment: I'm not really sure. Maybe make issue at https://github.com/confluentinc/ksql/issues ?